# Uninstalling XCode can interrupt MacPorts?

Tags: xcode, macports

I have Xcode 4.5 Developer Preview 1 and now I want to download Xcode 4.6. Before downloading the latest Xcode, I want to clean uninstall the old one. Not sure yet how to do that. But I'm afraid it will interrupt the [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) functions. [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) needs Xcode Command Line Tools. So is it possible to completely uninstall the old one first and then download the latest version later? I also want to upgrade Xcode 4.5 DP1 to Xcode 4.6 if possible. I installed Xcode 4.5 DP1 from DMG file. I'll install Xcode 4.6 from App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade XCode via App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upgrade Xcode and the command line tools without problems. MacPorts might not work while you don't have a version of Xcode (and the command line tools) installed, but will start working again after the update.